# How can I publish excel workbook with data populated using PowerQuery to SharePoint or website and have the data refresh on the site?

Tags: microsoft-excel, powerpivot

I have an Excel Workbook that gets data from an API using PowerQuery, to populate the tables.  There are also filters and slicers in the workbook.

**Is it possible to publish this workbook to SharePoint or another web site and have that data "refreshable" on that site without republishing?**

I am able to publish as a web page but the data is static.

I am currently using Excel 2010, but have access to all other versions.

Comment: AFAIK this is not supported.

Comment: I don't know of a means to do so specifically, but there might be a means of using ActiveX Data Objects to query your workbook as if it were a database. You won't get the nice filters and slices, though.

Alternatively, you could write a script and connect it to a scheduled task to periodically publish your workbook as a static web page.

Answer (score 0):

If you place the spreadsheet in a SharePoint document library, the spreadsheet will be available and will be able to the be refreshed. A SharePoint document library essentially functions as a network share with extra features.

If you need to display the spreadsheet itself in a SharePoint page, that can be done using Excel Services. Not all SharePoint environments have Excel Services available or enabled. With Excel Services available, you can place a live view of the spreadsheet in a web part on a page.